# CakePHP $ajax->submit submission after client side validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am new to cakePHP, I have submit button in cakePHP

`$ajax->submit(
    'Submit',
    array(
     "update" => "gridbox_script", 
     "url" => '/flots/comparaison_gridbox_update', 
     "div"=>"button_submit",
     "loading" => "setIboxOpacity = setOpacity;showBG();showIndicator();" , 
     "complete" => "hideBG();hideIndicator()" 
    )
);`

I would like to add one javascript validation, if the validation returns true then it should proceed for submission otherwise submission should be terminated.

The whole submission is calling through ajax and I was advised to use `$ajax` to implement.

my javascript function:

```
var firstCompare = new Array();
fucntion myValidation(){    
var otherCompare = new Array();
if(document.getElementById("file1").checked)
otherCompare.push('file1');
result = (otherCompare.length === _.intersection(otherCompare, firstCompare).length); 
firstCompare = otherCompare;
return result;
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the for id and check on submit or click event of your button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formId').on('submit', function() {
        var val = your_function()  //call the function and store the return value
        if (val) {
           //do the submission
        } else {
          //code in case of false
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I add javascript function inside cakePHP `$ajax->submit` ?

Comment: which cake version you are using?i think it is less than 2.x. you can write the function in the js file and use it as needed.